# pugjs(jade) template engine loading css file

Tags: css, node.js, pug, pugjs

I've been searching in the examples on the GitHub but I couldn't find how to load a simple css file into my layout. My first thought was doing something like this `link(href="my.css")` but it seems it's not working at all. The href points to a correct location online (checked and working) thus maybe I'm forgetting something?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

try: `link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')`

Answer (score 13):

I think you need to include the relationship. Try

`link(rel='stylesheet', href='my.css')`

Answer (score 13):

This works:

```
html
    head
        style
             include ./style.css
    body
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to add the type:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='my.css', type='text/css' )
```

Answer (score 3):

if you're using Jade with connect-assets, you can just use:

```
!= css('stylesheetName')
```

where `stylesheetName.css` is in your `assets/css/` directory.

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation for this?

Comment: @aaronfay This markup is made possible by the Node asset manager, _connect-assets_. It is one of three global functions provided by that module. https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets#markup-functions