# how to use css in jade?

Tags: css, node.js, pug

at last, i find it case by that express can not find the local css file.

### then i fix in my code.

i use the link word as told, but still can not see the css file invoke successful.

app.js

```
  var
    express = require('express')
  , cons = require('consolidate')
  , jade = require('jade')
  , path = require('path')

var app = express()

app.engine('jade', cons.jade)
app.use('/views',express.static(__dirname + '/views'))
app.use("/styles", express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade')

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.render('layout')
})

app.listen(3000);
```

/views/layout.jade

```
html
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='../styles/word.css', type='text/css')
head
  body
    p#para1 Just test css in jade.
```

/styles/word.css

```
p
{
text-align:center;
color:red;
}
```

it seems to be a silly problem, and i post too much code in the question, so thanks for reading at all

Comment: Have you checked Network Manager in Google Chrome or similar, to ensure the file is actually found?

Comment: Is it a typo, or do you try to load test.css while your css is in word.css ?

Comment: sorry, i already changed the test.css to word.css.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956038/jade-template-engine-loading-css-file

Comment: Possible ditch the relative require and define the href like soooo `href='/styles/word.css'`

Answer (score 0):

try starting the server, run the page, right click view source and click on your css link to see if it is actually linked to your page correctly.

if its not probably like what @grobot said it might be the directory problem.