# How to add css file link in pug

Tags: pug

I need to add css file named `feed.js` with a pug file named `feed.pug`.
i am trying this in feed.pug but it is not working

`link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='feed.css')`

this is my css code;

```
body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

I have also tried one or two solutions from stackoverflow but this is not working.
[pugjs(jade) template engine loading css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956038/pugjsjade-template-engine-loading-css-file)

Need help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might simply take a little messing around with finding the right location to use. I would imagine you need

```
link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/feed.css')
```

Note the forward slash in front of feed.css. On the server side, you need something like the below if you are using express.

```
var express = require('express');
app.use(express.static('css'));
```

Comment: In your base folder, do you have a folder called 'css'. Is your css file in that folder?

Comment: no i don't have any specific folder for css. I have one folder in which all css , js and html files are placed and only one ```views``` folder within that folder for pug.

Comment: Ah, you should try href='../feed.css'. These things can take a bit of tinkering. Also, on your server side, you need to have app.use(express.static('your_folder_for_static_files'))